# How to you get the address of an element in an std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory-address

For example, i have the following string :

```
std::string s = "Hello, World!"
```

I want the *address* of the last element of `s` which is `'!'`.

I tried the following code, but it does not seem to output what I want it to.

```
std::cout << &s[s.length() - 1];
```

That outputs `'!'` not it's address, the same happens with `s.back()`

Is it because of the formatting caused by `std::cout` or  is the problem elsewhere?

Basically I want a function that outputs the **address** of the last (and if possible, the first) element in a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, you're using the overload of `operator<<` that takes a `const char*` as input. It treats the input as a null-terminated C string.

If you cast to `(const void*)` the problem will go away:

```
std::cout << (const void*)(&s[s.length() - 1]);
```

Comment: My only complaint is that you use a C-style cast.. A `static_cast` should be preferred IMO. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I see your point, but I feel that's at the expense of readability at the call site. Perhaps I spent too much time in my youth programming in C ;-)

Comment: You're still in your youth!

Answer (score 1):

```
auto address_back = &s.back();
auto address_front = &s.front();

cout << static_cast<void*>(address_back) << endl;
cout << static_cast<void*>(address_front) << endl;
```